# Accessing parent domain from subdomain across frameworks

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a website: www.mydomain.com with it's CMS based in a sub-domain: cms.mydomain.com

The images for the site are in the folder www.mydomain.com/images and the subdomain is based in the folder www.mydomain.com/cms

The frontend website is built on plain html/css/php etc but the cms is built on top of CodeIgniter.

The document root for the main domain is /kunden/homepages/6/d10468022/htdocs while the document root for the sub-domain is /kunden/homepages/6/d10468022/htdocs/cms

My question is how do I set up CodeIgniter so that I can upload files via the cms to the images folder in the parent domain when the base_url in the config file is set to http ://cms.mydomain.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically file upload location is based on an absolute path and not on a URL such as produced by `base_url()`.

You can easily determine the path to the CMS and modify that string to be the location you want.

This answer depends on the CMS using the typical Codeigniter file structure.

In the CMS, the constant `FCPATH` is the server's absolute path to the folder where the 'front controller' (index.php) is located. In your case it is probably something along the lines of `/kunden/homepages/6/d10468022/htdocs/cms/`. (This might have other directories before /kunden. That's OK.) Note that `FCPATH` will contain a trailing directory separator.

All you need to do is replace the 'cms/' part of the string with 'images'.

```
$image_path = str_replace ("cms/", 'images', FCPATH);
```

`$image_path` should now be `/kunden/homepages/6/d10468022/htdocs/images`.

How you use the var `$image_path` depends on how the CMS goes about storing uploaded files.

Comment: That appears to do the trick; I think it was the FCPATH constant that I was unaware of that was my problem.

Comment: There are several other constants defined in Codeigniter's "front controller" (/FCPATH/index.php) that you may find useful for other circumstances. Check them out.